# Ubuntuサーバー上でSCPからのアクセス履歴を調べる方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu(16.04)で自作サーバーを管理しております。アクセスの履歴を調べる方法についてお伺いしたく質問しました。

PuTTYなどのsshでサーバーにログインしますと、サーバー側のアクセス履歴は `last` や `who` コマンドで確認できることは理解しております。

質問は、SCP(例えばWinSCP)などでファイル転送をする時に、誰がアクセスしているのかを知る方法はありますでしょうか？

自分で試したことは、WinSCPを使ってサーバーにアクセスし、幾つかのファイルを移動させ、WinSCPをログアウトしました。この状態で、putty-sshを使って、同じサーバーにアクセスして、`last` や `who` で検索しても、WinSCPからログインした履歴が残っておりませんでした。WinSCP以外にもfiletransferのソフトを使っても同じ状況でした。

このような状況で、履歴を探すことは可能でしょうか？

ご教授していただけると、助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 要望の機能があるか不明ですが、この記事とそこからのリンク先で何かできるかも。[【メモ】scpのファイル転送結果をログにはく方法](https://syunkan81.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/09/23/203140)

Comment: `sshd_config` に `SyslogFacility` や `LogLevel` などの設定項目がありますが、Ubuntu でのデフォルトの設定では `/var/log/auth.log` に接続・認証の履歴が記録されていると思います。

Comment: @metropolis コメント欄ではなく、回答として投稿して頂けませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scp` (および `sftp`) では SSH を介してファイルの転送を行うので、ログインに関する情報が欲しいのであれば `/var/log/auth.log` を確認してみてください。

**参考:**
[Where would you find SCP logs? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/659896)

Comment: @metropolis様、@cubick♦様、ありがとうございます！suで実行しないといけませんが、WinSCPからの接続履歴がauth.logで確認できました。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。